# understanding print option in rrdtool

Tags: rrdtool

Instead of creating a graph, I need to simply output a number that is the average, max or min of some date range supplied. I have had good success with the following code:

```
rrdtool graph a.png --start=1325484000 --end=1364472365 DEF:power=/data1/bpoll/rrd/ws3/pdu/pdu316/a.rrd:ct12:AVERAGE 'PRINT:power:AVERAGE:%2.1lf'
```

However, looking at the docu, it says specifying the `CF` (in this case AVERAGE) is deprecated. Yet I am completely lost as to the new format. At least I can't seem to wrap my head around it. If I leave out the `CF`, it errors. Where exactly am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
PRINT:power:AVERAGE:%2.1lf
```

This is the 'old style' syntax, where you pass a dataset and the consolodation function to the `PRINT` directive.

With the new format, you use a `VDEF` and so do not need a function as a `VDEF` is single-valued.  However, you need to define the `VDEF` beforehand.

This is the new format:

```
VDEF:avgpower:power,AVERAGE
PRINT:avgpower:%2.1lf
```

In this example, we define a new `VDEF` value `avgpower` and print that.  It has the same effect as the previous old syntax code, but is in the new sytax, which allows us to also add modifiers to the `PRINT` statement such as `:strftime` to print the point in time of maxima, and so on.